# Download from gitHub

Tags: file, github, download

How I can download this file from GitHub?

https://github.com/TorgeirH90/Programming/tree/master/C%23/Paratroopers%20Mono/Paratroopers%20Mono

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask a question here. Stack Overflow is for specific programming problems. Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help] as a start..

Comment: I think you are trying to clone the github project on your local machine. In git hub, Clone means the copy of replica of github project. You can clone from http or ssh, so, you can do by two way . First is: git clone https://github.com/TorgeirH90/Programming.git
or, do: git clone git@github.com:TorgeirH90/Programming.git
Hope, this may help you. I copied those clone url from the project repo which you have been posted on this question. Thanks.

Comment: -> how do [download|clone] only one file|subdirectory from remote git repository in one command. Eg. to be used with `npm install --save <url|command>`.

Comment: Got to the page of the project (https://github.com/TorgeirH90/Programming), click on "Code" and then "Download ZIP".